# javascript. Storing multiple arrays into a table after an input loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I am currently trying to learn how to code with javascript and I must create a table for a multiple list of arrays that the user(s) had to input before hand. And I'd like to request on some guidance on the best way to accomplish this.

My current code I've started so far that I haven't completed:

```
    "use strict"


var plans = ["trial", "standard", "premium", "unlimited"];
var inpPlans; // plans input
var ayyl;
for(var i = 0; i<5 && inpPlans != ""; i++ ){
    inpPlans= prompt("Please select a plan. \nAnswer with nothing to cancel.").toLowerCase();
    ayyl = plans.indexOf(inpPlans);
    if(-1 === ayyl)
        alert("Plans available: " + plans);
}




var customerName = [];
var nameInp; // Customer name input

for(var i = 0; i<10 && nameInp != ""; i++){
    nameInp = prompt("Please provide your name. \nAnswer with nothing to cancel. ", "");
    customerName.push(nameInp); 
}

var textSent = [];
var textInp; // Text amount input

for(var i = 0; i<10 && textInp != ""; i++){
    textInp = prompt("Please provide amount of texts. \nAnswer with nothing to cancel. ", 0);
    textSent.push(textInp);
}




if (customerName != ""){
    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = "<table><thead><tr><th>Customer</th><th>Plan type</th><th>Cost</th><th>Extra Texts</th><th>Charges</th><th>Customer Total</th><th>Running Total</th></tr></thead>";
            for(var i = 0; i<customerName.length; i++){
                document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + customerName[i] + "</td></td>";
                document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML += "<tr><td align='right'>" + plans[i] + "</td></tr></table>";
            }
} else {
    document.getElementById("summary").innerHTML = "<span style='color:Navy;font-weight:bold;'>Customer name is empty. <br>Aborting...<\/span>";

}
```

I wanted the output to look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRk09.png)

But instead got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PzRV.png)